# Nested Scrolling in Android using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I am not able to implement nested scroll behaviour in my jetpack compose based app

I have used `LazyColumn{ item{}}` but still getting this error:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a header before the list of items please add a header as a separate item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout. Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the hierarchy above the scrolling container.` 
I am not making a traditional list, I just have alot of elements that are too big to fit on the screen. Therefore I want the column to scroll so I can see all the elements. Here is my code

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val productViewModel: ProductViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val categoryViewModel:CategoryViewModel= hiltViewModel()
    val categoryState by categoryViewModel.category.collectAsState()
    val productState by productViewModel.product.collectAsState()
    val images = listOf("https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2021/08/11/gettyimages-1279899488_wide-f3860ceb0ef19643c335cb34df3fa1de166e2761-s1100-c50.jpg",
        "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/20/18/03/cat-2083492__480.jpg",
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRrfPnodZbEjtJgE-67C-0W9pPXK8G9Ai6_Rw&usqp=CAU",
        "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/E9iP8jdtYZ0/maxresdefault.jpg",
        "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0535/2738/0144/articles/shutterstock_149121098_360x.jpg")
    
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(8.dp)
    ){
        item {
                SearchBar()
                ImageSlider(images)
        }

        item{
                Row{
                    Text(text = "Shop by Category", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    Text(text="See all...", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                }
                Categories(categoryState = categoryState)
        }

        item {
            Row{
                Text(text = "Shop by Category", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                Text(text="See all...",modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            }
        }

        item{
            Products(productState = productState)
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        productViewModel.getAllProducts()
        categoryViewModel.getAllCategory()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Products(productState:NetworkResult<List<Product>?>?) {
    when (productState) {
        is NetworkResult.Success -> {
            LazyColumn{
                items(productState.data!!) { product ->
                    ProductItem(product = product)
                }
            }
        }
        is NetworkResult.Error -> {
            val errorMessage = productState.message
            Text("Error loading products: $errorMessage")
        }

        is NetworkResult.Loading -> {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
        else ->{
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Categories(categoryState:NetworkResult<List<Category>?>?) {
    when (categoryState) {
        is NetworkResult.Success -> {
            LazyRow {
                items(categoryState.data!!) { category ->
                    CategoryItem(category = category)
                }
            }
        }
        is NetworkResult.Error -> {
            val errorMessage = categoryState.message
            Text("Error loading products: $errorMessage")
        }

        is NetworkResult.Loading -> {
            // Show a loading indicator or skeleton screen
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
        else ->{
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using Column and LazyColumn but still not able to resolve it

Comment: You have one option for that. you can set fixed hide of inner component and as like you can use it. but inner and outer component with maxheight not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `LazyColumn` inside `MainScreen` contains the `Products` Composable, which itself contains another `LazyColumn`. Nesting two Composables that scroll into the same direction [is not permitted in Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#avoid-nesting-scrollable) when both are (implicitly) using `fillMaxHeight()`.

In order to resolve this, your options are as follows:

**A)** Set the nested `LazyColumn` to a fixed height:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)
) {
    items(productState.data!!) { product ->
        ProductItem(product = product)
    }
}
```

**B)** Display the Products in a `LazyRow` instead of a `LazyColumn` and add the option to open a vertical list of Products on a new screen.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid nesting components that can scroll in the same direction. While this is permitted in Android XML structure, Compose discourages this practice. If you're already using LazyColumn, you'll be able to scroll down when the content doesn't fit on the screen.

[Lazy Layout in Compose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ANt65eoNhQ&t=897s&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers)